# Brush effect on page through canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on functionality where I have to create a brush-like an effect on the web page.

The requirement is that there will be multiple patterns/textures available in the background. And the user will drag the mouse to create the effect of that pattern on the page.

Below is the **JSFiddle link** where I have created the structure, I am able to create the pattern, but I am unsure of how to create the brush-like effect.

I have added the brush image as a data source in my [`JSFiddle Link`](https://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/3yr2kp4c/1/)

I am a beginner in canvas and don't have any idea about how to move forward. Please let me know if I am going in the right direction.

Check the [`Reference Website`](https://art4globalgoals.com) where this functionality is running and working.

Comment: Apologies if my question is very simple, I am a beginner in canvas, I have tried few things but that didn't work. Can anybody give me an idea.

Comment: So your current brush is an arc from 0 to 10 radians (or about 573 degrees which becomes 213 degrees). If you create a brush that is a path, you could just substitute it for the arc you have there now. If you need the brush to be an image, this becomes more complicated.

Comment: @aptriangle: I have created an arc to achieve the first step, of revealing the pattern in the background, and now the next step is to create the brush effect, while dragging the mouse.

Comment: @aptriangle: I don't know actually what the next step is. I mean how to achieve this.

Comment: Revealing the pattern is what the brush does. You have created an arc shaped brush. The brush in the reference website looks like a lot of little circles in a pattern. If you want yours to look similar, replace the arc brush with a lot of little circles brush.

Comment: @aptriangle I have thoroughly checked the reference website and they are using brush image.

Comment: Well, to use a brush mask with the canvas 2d context, I would draw the brush mask to an offscreen canvas, which would accumulate all the drawings of the brush mask. For each frame I would clear the visible canvas, draw the full pattern image to the visible canvas, then set the blend mode to destination-in and draw the offscreen canvas to the visible canvas, which would remove all the parts of the pattern image that the brush wasn't covering. You could also use PIXI.js like the reference site.

Comment: @aptriangle Yes, they are also using the PIXI.js

Comment: Can I create my own custom brush effect ?
Can anybody give me an idea ?

Comment: @aptriangle How to create a lot of little circles, to create the brush effect ?

Comment: I made a modification to your code that creates random bristles and then draws them as circles. You will probably want to choose bristle positions so that they are organized in the way you want, not random, but this at least shows how to convert the array of bristle positions into a brush: https://jsfiddle.net/z43udtLn/

Comment: @aptriangle You are good.

Comment: @aptriangle I have doubled the bristles, it's running slow, I am trying to fix that.

Comment: @aptriangle: I have used your code (https://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/3yr2kp4c/8/), but still there are performance issues.
Can you help me in that ?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://github.com/tennisonchan/fabric-brush

Comment: @VarunChakervarti have you tried adjusting your mouse/touchpad settings? it doesn't run v slow on my computer? I know this is not a universal fix, but worth having a look at if you are having local issues

Answer (score 1):

Well for a basic brush effect, instead of drawing a single large dot, you can instead draw a bunch of smaller dots, each dot representing a single brush stroke. You can also add variable width to the strokes if you want but that is upto you.
This is a basic brush example, instead of drawing a circle, draw it like this:
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huqw4Lt8/131/)

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let drawCheck = false;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#808080";
let points = 40;
let offsets = [];
let radius = 50;
let prev = {
  x: -1,
  y: -1
};
let curr = {
  x: -1,
  y: -1
};

for (let i = 0; i < points; i++) {
  offsets.push([Math.random() * radius * (-1) ** i, Math.random() * radius * (-1) ** i, 1 + Math.random() * 4]);
}

function draw(x, y) {
  curr.x = x;
  curr.y = y;

  if (drawCheck) {
    if (prev.x == -1) {
      offsets.forEach(offset => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(curr.x + offset[0], curr.y + offset[1], 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        prev.x = curr.x;
        prev.y = curr.y;
      });
    } else {
      offsets.forEach(offset => {
      ctx.lineWidth = offset[2];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prev.x + offset[0], prev.y + offset[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(curr.x + offset[0], curr.y + offset[1]);
        ctx.stroke();
      })
      prev.x = curr.x;
      prev.y = curr.y;
    }

  }
}

document.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => drawCheck = true);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) =>
  draw(e.clientX, e.clientY));
document.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
  drawCheck = false;
  prev = {
    "x": -1,
    "y": -1
  };
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" height=320 width=600></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```